# install setuptools and python wheels on disconnected networks

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

I do a lot of work on machines that are not connected to the Internet. I can easily move a Python wheel `.whl` file to the machine, but it's not clear how to install it --- when I type `pip install filename.whl` pip tries to go to the Internet and then fails.

Comment: Installing a wheel requires `pip` and `setuptools`. But to instal `pip` and `setuptools` you have to install from sources.

Comment: You have to download the wheel and all its dependencies. On a machine with internet access: `pip download pkgname --dest wheelhouse/`, copy `wheelhouse` to machine without internet access, there run `pip install pkgname --no-index --find-links=wheelhouse/`

Comment: Hi @hoefling, it would be useful for you to post this as an answer, rather than a comment. For example, is there a way to automatically find all of the dependencies that are not included in the standard distribution?